# Jinja templates and Empty query results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I am using a query using sqlalchemy that I know should return no results.  For example:

```
employees = User.query.filter_by(company_id = 999999)
```

This correctly returns no results and I send this to my template...  Then I use the HTML:

```
{% if employees %}
<p> Why do I get printed? </p>
{% endif %}
```

so "employees" exists, but it is empty.  How can I test for this?

I have also unsuccessfully tried:

```
{% if employees is not none %}
<p> Why do I get printed? </p>
{% endif %}
```

How do I make the `if` statement evaluate to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

`if employees.count() == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Safe to use, and works for null or empty employees

```
{% if employees| length %}
<p> Why do I get printed? </p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: for some reason when trying this I get an error that the BaseObject has no length property... but using.count() does work.

Comment: My bad. The built in filter is length. I edited the anwser.

Comment: Are you using a filter or a property?